Unable to find definition of mvc:cors
I am on a Spring 4, java 8 project trying to pick up the pieces from previous mis-handling.
I am tasked with restoring a version of web services missing from source control. I am doing this by de-compiling the war and putting the changes back in the source. While doing this, I found the following lines in applicationContext.xml.
    <mvc:cors>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"
                     allowed-origins="*"
                     allowed-methods="POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE"
                     allowed-headers="*"
                     allow-credentials="false"
                     max-age="4800" />
    </mvc:cors>

And I copied them into my applicationContext.xml. I Immediately got the following error.
   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 67 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 67; columnNumber: 13; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:cors'.
The beans definitions with the xmlns are identical between the versions:
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:mybatis="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring 
    http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd"
    >

I looked in the spring-mvc def, but there was nothing about cors there.
I did some searching, and while there's sites that tell you how to use cors like this, none of them specify the namespace to use to bring this in.
Does anyone have any advice?

The mvc:cors element is available since Spring 4.2, so if you are on a version before that it simply isn't available. Also 4.x, really, that has been out of support for ages. Also if you have source control where is the history, as that is the whole point of source control.

@M.Deinum Thanks for explaining source control to me. Please explain it to the previous devs who didn’t bother to check in their changes.

@M.Deinum's comments (despite being patronizing) were spot on. In addition to the lost source, they also evidently made changes to the build and I was building with the wrong libraries. Correcting that fixed my issue.
